# IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition SDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently downloaded IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition from JetBrains. After installing it, I ran it and found that there was an error. It said that the SDK has not been set up and it told me to do it. I tried many folders in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk..., but it kept replying that those folders were not "home folders" for the SDK. Please help!

Comment: So, what do you think is the folder that is the home of the JDK? What's in that folder?

Comment: SDK usually stands for `Sofware Development Kit` which does not make much sense here. did you mean `JDK`?

Comment: @JBNizet 
I placed it in Java\jre1.80... and tried other folders too.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. `Java\jdk1.80...` is not a valid absolute path, and that doesn't tell me what is in that folder.

Comment: @hotzst 
IntelliJ said to Setup SDK, I clicked on the button that said "Setup SDK" and then it opened a browsing window that shows all of my folders and files.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by what is in the folder.

Comment: When you fo to that folder in the command window and type `dir`, what's the output. When you click on that folder in the left pane of the explorer, what is displayed in the right pane?

Comment: @JBNizet
Inside the folder there is bin(folder), lib(folder), COPYRIGHT, LICENSE, README, release, READMETHIRDPARTY, and that's pretty much it.

Comment: That is a JRE installation. The JRE is the Java Runtime Environment. It allows running Java programs. But not creating Java programs (compiling, creating jars, etc.). Download the **JDK** and install it. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: I already have a JDK though.

Comment: Then choose the directory where the JDK is installed. Not the directory where the JRE is installed.

Comment: Okay, tried it and it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out the actual issue was not about SDK, but about JDK which stands for Java Development Kit. It is required to set up the JDK before doing any Java programming in Intellij IDEA and by setting up I mean choosing the folder where JDK is located. JDK can be downloaded from [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).